# Relationship between "close" for PreparedStatement and Connection?

Tags: java, database, prepared-statement

Javadoc says for `.close()` of the `PreparedStatement` says that it ..

> Releases this Statement object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed. It is generally good practice to release
>   resources as soon as you are finished with them to avoid tying up
>   database resources.
>
> Calling the method close on a Statement object that is already closed has no effect.
>
> Note:When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

Consider the following scenario

```
    MyConnector databaseConnector = DBManager.instance().getConnector();

    Connection con = databaseConnector.getConnection(); // returns java.sql.Connection
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    try {
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("some query");
         ...
    } finally {  
        if (pstmt != null)
            pstmt.close();
    }
```

In this example, will `pstmt.close()` also close `con`?

Comment: No. Closing a statement will *not* close the connection (as there may be *many* statements for a single connection). The connection should *also* be considered a managed resource.

Comment: You can always test this yoursef, with "con.isClosed()"
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Closing a `Statement` *doesn't* close a `Connection`.  However, closing a `Connection` *will* close a `Statement`.

Think of it like so:

- Connection -> creates and automatically closes -> Statement
- Statement -> creates and automatically closes -> ResultSet

So closing a `Connection` will automatically close any `Statement`s *and* any `ResultSet`s it contains.

However, it's still considered best practice to close all three manually (`ResultSet` followed by `Statement` followed by `Connection`) if possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: When a *Statement* object is closed, its current *ResultSet* [but not Connection] object, if one exists, is also closed.

It wont close connection, it just closes resultset object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7 and **`try-with-resources`** you don't need to worry about closing the connection or any of the `Statement` or `ResultSet`.

```
try (Connection conn = databaseConnector.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("some query")) {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Seems like closing the connection automatically closes the prepared statement. Is it still best practice to have the prepared statement explicitly in the resources block?